# How to hide header only in first page of each section with fancyhdr?

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I want the header to be empty in the page were section begins and showed in the other pages. How can I do that?

```
\documentclass[12pt, titlepage, onecolumn, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}    %% for dummy text

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}} % set the \leftmark
\fancyhf{}

\lhead{\leftmark}
\chead{}
\rhead{\rightmark}
\cfoot{\footnotesize\selectfont\bfseries\thepage}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{8pt}

\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thesection.\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\thesection.\arabic{table}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
  \pagenumbering{roman}
  \setcounter{page}{2}
\lipsum[1]
  \rhead{\footnotesize{\thesection{ } \leftmark}}
  \pagenumbering{arabic}
  \setcounter{page}{1}
\section{First Section}
\lipsum[2-5]
\section{Second Section}
\lipsum[2-8]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure what do you mean by `empty` but if you are looking for the normal layout without the *text* of the header you can add this pagestyle to your preamble:

```
\fancypagestyle{FooBar}{%
    \fancyhead{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
}
```

and then start your sections by declaring

```
\section{Second Section}\thispagestyle{FooBar}
```

This will give you

[image]

If you literally need an ***empty*** layout, you can use `\thispagestyle{empty}` as it is already defined by the package (an other predefined style is `plain`).

Comment: it was the FooBar solution what I was looking for.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

You can make the choice automatic, by adding some code to `\section`

```
\documentclass[12pt, titlepage, onecolumn, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{xparse}

\usepackage{lipsum}    %% for dummy text

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}} % set the \leftmark
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[C]{\footnotesize\bfseries\thepage}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt} % <-------- 8pt is too small!

\fancypagestyle{section}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyfoot[C]{\footnotesize\bfseries\thepage}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}%
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}%
}


\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\counterwithin{table}{section}

% the starting page of a section will not have a header
\let\originalsection\section
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{som}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\originalsection*{#3}}
    {\IfNoValueTF{#2}
      {\originalsection{#3}}
      {\originalsection[#2]{#3}}%
    }%
  \thispagestyle{section}%
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\section{First Section}
\lipsum[2-5]
\section{Second Section}
\lipsum[2-8]
\end{document}
```

I added also the correct size for `\headheight` (unless you use a smaller font 14.5pt is necessary). Also I removed the setting of `\rightmark`, add it if really wanted, but then you probably have to redefine `\subsectionmark`.

Also I defined the counters for tables and figures using `chngcntr` and `\counterwithin`; this way the counters will be reset at each section.

Comment: Nice answer! Unfortunately the right- and leftmarks are gone so it will alwasy print the table of contents title as title when the header is printed again.

Comment: @Tim I'm not sure what you mean. I tried with an extended example filling two pages of the TOC, but the headers are as expected.

Comment: I implemented this answer and your answer from tex-sx id:101915 together. Atleast when having it together the leftmark and rightmark is gone. Instead I always have the german translation of "toc" in my header. Before I implemented this answer it worked. But nonetheless this answer worked as expected besides the toc in header now.

Comment: If it's still not clear I can upload a MWE here.

Comment: @Tim You should ask a fresh question, linking to this answer.

Comment: It was hard to form the question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/344405/how-to-hide-customized-header-on-section-start

Answer (score 3):

It can also be achieved if you define the \fancypagestyle, as Pouya did:

```
\fancypagestyle{FooBar}{% 
   \fancyhead{}
   \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
}
```

and somewhere in the preamble (before `\begin{document}`) state:

```
\let \OldSection \section
\renewcommand{\section}[1]{\OldSection{#1} \thispagestyle{FooBar}}
```

:: Update ::

In my case, sometimes, I want to open a section on a new page, using memoir.
So, I use the following tex:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}    %% for dummy text

\let\footruleskip\undefined
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

% Apply section style
\let \OldSection \section
\renewcommand{\section}[1]{\OldSection{#1} \thispagestyle{plainsec}}


% Define your page styles
\pagestyle{fancy}               
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
\markboth{\chaptername
\ \thechapter\ - #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{%
            \markright{\thesection\ - #1}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\bfseries\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries\leftmark}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\addtolength{\headheight}{0.5pt}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{  %chapter openning
        \fancyhf{}
        \fancyhead[RO]{\bfseries\thepage}
        \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}
\fancypagestyle{plainsec}{  %section openning
        \fancyhf{}
        \fancyhead[RO]{\bfseries\thepage}
        \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}


\begin{document}
\chapter{First Chapter}
\lipsum[1]
\section{A Section after some text}
\lipsum[2-5]
\subsection{A Sub-section}
\lipsum[2-5]

\cleardoublepage
\section{A Section at a new page}
\lipsum[2-8]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please elaborate on this and show a screen shot, for example

Comment: I add an example above. 
If you want, you can define a specific section command, whenever you need a section opening like a chapter usually does.